# How to implement laravel in ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, virtualbox

I just installed an Ubuntu server on virtualbox and moved my laravel project to it's /html folder. After configuring Laravel.conf and my server, this is what I get to see:

[image: Root page in browser]

It does not show the public folder, however I can visit it through /public, but no links are working. This is my Laravel.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
     ServerName 192.168.1.104

     <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone knows what miskake I'm making?

Comment: What happens when you click on the public folder ?

Comment: Where's your laravel.conf file located?

Comment: @ABDELLATIFLAKEHAL it shows the correct index page, however when I click on a link it breaks.

Comment: @PeterSowah in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

Comment: @jason deru how it breaks ? What error arr u getting ? Make sure to enable php error reporting

Comment: @ABDELLATIFLAKEHAL it returns a 404..

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem  ***the public folder is not showing but you can visit it***. this is because the `.htaccess` file is disabling directory listing withing public folder

For your second problem which is ***you are unable to visit laravel index page links*** this is because laravel rewrite url rules are not working and to enable them you sould enable apache2 rewrite module as follow :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart your webserver

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

now your problem should be fixed.

Comment: I already enabled a2enmod rewrite, what changes do I need to make to .htaccess?